# I want to know mouse wheel control vertical carousel in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmxW2.jpg)| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   |
| Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
I am using reference website realticket.com I am trying to do that effect in react but it's not working properly

I am expecting how to get that particular effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am not getting idea to create that effect